# How can I sum the first index and last index until the len(list) = 2?

Tags: python, list, loops

Im trying to get a percentaje from a list of numbers, but it is a little different than the usual methods.

Bassically I need to sum the first index of the list with the last index of the same list. I want the script to do this repeatedly until the lenght of the list equals 2.

Something like this:

```
list = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
list = [2, 2, 3, 2, 2]
list = [4, 4, 3]
list = [7, 4] #here the lenght = 2, so it stops.

final_list = [7, 4]

percentaje = f"%{final_list[0]}{final_list[1]}"
#OUTPUT
#"%74"
```

Can someone help me to do this? Im not so good with loops :(

Answer (score 0):

This?

```
L = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

while len(L) > 2:
    new_L = [L[i]+L[len(L)-1-i] for i in range(len(L)//2)]
    if len(L)%2:
        new_L.append(L[len(L)//2]) # add middle term alone if any
    L = new_L

print(f"%{L[0]}{L[1]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list1 = [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
while len(list1)!=2:
    for i in range (0, int(len(list1)/2)):
        list1[i] = list1[i] + list1[len(list1)-1]
        list1 = list1[:-1]
print(list1)
```

output:
[7, 4]

Comment: This is rather inefficient for large lists...